# How to compile .rb files in my google appengine project

Tags: ruby, eclipse, google-app-engine, compilation, jruby

I have created a google appengine project in Eclipse and this project has mixture of .java and .rb files. Is there a way to automatically compile .rb files whenever it is changed (like how java files are compiled). And if there is a way can the command that is run be customized?

Thanks,
Prabhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.igvita.com/2009/09/23/deploying-jruby-on-google-app-engine/ for deploying jRuby directly to Google App Engine.

http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyCompiler , for jruby compiler